How to use 心/胸を焦がす in a grammatical sense?
I am currently studying the lyrics of Kaleidoscope by 茶太; I have a playlist of Japanese songs, so by studying their lyrics I have a free study list I can listen to while doing something else.
I encountered this phrase in one of the lyrics, with a focus on 「心を焦がす」:

手に入らぬからこそ、人は心を焦がす

This means "Precisely because [dreams] do not fall into one's hands (easy to get), people yearn."
I am aware that 胸/心 are interchangeable to the phrase, but in any case, I am unsure how to grammatically use this phrase. I wanted to make a joke sentence like "the children yearn for the mines," but all examples of the phrase online do not seem to offer how I might say this; thus far I have this:

子供が洞窟(...)胸を焦がしている。

But I am unsure how to proceed with the particle. I found this example online that does modify the phrase with の:

未知の可能性への胸を焦がす, "Yearn towards possibilities unknown"

Does anyone have any further understanding on how to use this phrase or phrases similar to it? Is this phrase in some kind of の-category of sorts?

So I guess the question is, when you're trying to translate "the children yearn for the mines", how to deal with the "for"?

My attempt at translating that sentence made me realize that I do not know how to grammatically use 心を焦がす, as no examples online provided a clear grammatical context outside of "Subject yearns." It seems that I should be able to use 心を焦がす in the situation even as a joke, and my dictionary says "yearn for," but I do not know what grammar to use to represent "for."

First, 心を焦がす (or 胸を焦がす) is an expression that would be suitable in lyrics or other creative writings, but it's not really a common idiom for "to yearn". It would sound melodramatic if used in daily conversation, and I'm not sure if I have used it even once in my entire life. (Xに)思い焦がれる and (Xに)恋い焦がれる are still slightly dramatic words, but would be safer for daily use.
Besides, as you can probably imagine from the literal meaning of 焦がす, these phrases are usually used in the context of unrequited love or similar situations that will occupy your mind for a prolonged period. It would be odd to use them to say something generic and casual like "Children love dinosaurs" or "People yearn for the unknown". For these, you can say 恐竜に憧れる, 未知のものにロマンを感じる, etc.
If you still want to use 心を焦がす to convey "to yearn for X", you can say:

Xを思って心を焦がす
Xに心を焦がす


子供たちが…洞窟に心を焦がしてるんだぜ。

@BigRigz This sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds as if a beautiful demon is inside a cave, casting a spell from within to allure all the children of the town :)
